# Tensorflowjs convert fails for a frozen model

Tags: tensorflowjs-converter

TensorFlow.js model converters.: error: argument --input_format: invalid choice: 'tf_frozen_model' (choose from 'keras', 'tfjs_layers_model', 'tensorflowjs', 'tf_saved_model', 'tf_hub', 'keras_saved_model')
Trying to convert a frozen model but every time i run i get the above error

Comment: Please help its urgent

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that saving a frozen model has been depreciated. You need to use tensorflowjs version 0.8.6.

```
pip install tensorflowjs==0.8.6
```